# How to show that $\operatorname{span} (A)=\mathbb{R}^3$ where $A=\{(t,t^2,t^3):t\in \mathbb{R}\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $A=\{(t,t^2,t^3):t\in \mathbb{R}\}$. Show that $\operatorname{span} (A)=\mathbb{R}^3$.

---

[**My thoughts**.]

In order to show  $\text{span} (A)=\mathbb{R}^3$ I have to show that every vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a linear combination of vectors in $A$. But I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Google Vandermonde matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Take, for example, $t=1$, $t=2$ and $t=3$ and show that $\left(1,1^2,1^3\right)$, $\left(2,2^2,2^3\right)$ and $\left(3,3^2,3^3\right)$ are linearly independent and hence span the (three-dimensional) space $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @StackTD..how to we prove it

Comment: @Suresh_iit The same way you show that any set of vectors is linearly independent (in other words, there is nothing special about this one). One way is to take a linear combination of them that adds up to $\vec 0$, then show that the linear combination must have all coefficients $0$.

Comment: @Suresh_iit See above (Arthur's answer); equivalently you can put them in a 3 by 3 matrix and verify that the determinant is non-zero, this gives you a more "direct, computational" way.

Comment: @StackTD.....suppose $(x,y,z)\in R^3$ and $(x,y,z)=a(t,t^2,t^3)+b(t,t^,t^3)+c(t,t^2,t^3)$ like this way going to solve ?

Comment: @Arthur...here is single vector is there then how to write linear combiamtion..i missing something i think..sorry

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach: the [moment curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_curve) is not a planar curve, since its [torsion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_of_a_curve) is given by

$$ \tau =\frac{((1,2t,3t^2)\times(0,2,6t))\cdot(0,0,6)}{\|(1,2t,3t^2)\times(0,2,6t) \|^2}=\frac{3}{1+9t^2+9t^4}\neq 0. $$

*$3\times 3$ real Vandermonde matrices are invertible since the moment curve is non-planar* is a nice way to put it. In the classical way, given three distinct real numbers $a,b,c$, the problem of finding a solution to
$$ \begin{pmatrix}1 & a & a^2 \\ 1 & b & b^2 \\ 1 & c & c^2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}k_1 \\ k_2 \\ k_3\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}y_1 \\ y_2 \\ y_3\end{pmatrix}$$
given $y_1,y_2,y_3\in\mathbb{R}$ is equivalent to finding the coefficients of a quadratic polynomial $q$ such that $q(a)=y_1, q(b)=y_2, q(c)=y_3$. A solution always exists, by Lagrange's interpolating polynomials, and such a solution is also unique. It follows that the matrix appearing in the LHS is invertible, hence if $A,B,C\neq 0$ are three distinct points on the moment curve, $\text{Span}(A,B,C)=\mathbb{R}^3$.